# how deploy a full stack react and spring boot to be seen on internet?

Tags: reactjs, deployment

Hello I create an app wth React and SpringBoot and Postgres and I don't know how to deploy on the net and get an internet address to put and show on portfolio and recruiters ? Thx a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest you to deploy your app to [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/) it's quite friendly for new programmers and there is tone of tutorials about it also the documentation is easy to follow like for [Spring Boot](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-spring-boot-apps-to-heroku) or [React SPA](https://blog.heroku.com/deploying-react-with-zero-configuration). There is also easy way to create a [postgres db](https://www.heroku.com/postgres). There are free plans for all of that, downside is that in free plan after about 30(?) min idle your app will be shoutdown and will start again when someone request it (it cause a little delay).

You can then send send a link to your website/REST api to recruiters.